# Is there an Julia function to transform coordinate reference system (e. g. st_transform in R)?

Tags: r, julia, coordinates, geospatial, r-sf

I have an .shp file with ETRS89 / Poland CS92 coordinates and I want to transform it to WGS84[long/lat].
Example of transformation for a point:

```
ETRS89 / Poland CS92: (184074.7, 682954.7) --> WGS84: (14.18703, 53.91454)
```

In `R` it could be done using `st_transform` function from `sf` library:

```
st_transform(polska_grid, "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84+datum=WGS84")
```

Is there function like `st_transform` in Julia?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is the `reproject` function from ArchGDAL that gets further extended by GeoDataFrames. That will offer a similar transform to sf, like so:

```
import GeoDataFrames as GDF
import GeoFormatTypes as GFT

df = GDF.read("path/to/a.shp")
df.geometry = GDF.reproject(df.geometry, GFT.EPSG(2180), GFT.EPSG(4326))
```

This example uses GeoDataFrames.jl v0.3.

Relevant documentation is here:

- https://www.evetion.nl/GeoDataFrames.jl/dev/tutorials/ops/#Reprojection
- https://yeesian.com/ArchGDAL.jl/dev/projections/